# how to access jsp arraylist object in action class

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts2

I am having `paidList` `ArrayList` in action  I am iterating it and getting appropriate value now again I am submitting this `paidList`(to update its value) into update() and printing its value in output window, it is showing simple value but not able to show value of `getPaidList().get(0).getCashActionList()`,`getDDActionList()` ,`getOnlineActionList()`

index.jsp

```
<s:form action="UpdatedPaid" method="post">  
    <s:if test="paidList.size>0"> 
        <s:iterator value="paidList" var="pdlst">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Amount</span>
                <span class="ib"> 
                    <s:hidden name="paidId" id="paidId">
                        <s:param name="value">
                            <s:property value="paidId"/>
                        </s:param>
                    </s:hidden>
                    <s:textfield name="amount" id="amount">
                        <s:param name="value">
                            <s:property value="amount"/>
                        </s:param>
                    </s:textfield>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Payment Date</span>
                <span class="ib"> <s:textfield name="paymentDate" id="paymentDate">
                        <s:param name="value">
                            <s:property value="paymentDate"/>
                        </s:param>
                    </s:textfield>
                </span>
            </div>
            <s:if test="cashActionList.size>0"> 
                <s:iterator value="cashActionList" var="calst">
                    <div class="box">
                        <span class="label">TO Person</span>
                        <span class="ib">
                            <s:hidden name="id" id="id">
                                <s:param name="value">
                                    <s:property value="id"/>
                                </s:param>
                            </s:hidden>
                            <s:textfield name="toPerson" id="toPerson">
                                <s:param name="value">
                                    <s:property value="toPerson"/>
                                </s:param>
                            </s:textfield>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </s:iterator>
            </s:if>
            <s:if test="DDActionList.size>0"> 
                <s:iterator value="DDActionList" var="calst">
                </s:iterator>
            </if>
            <s:if test="OnlineActionList.size>0">
                <s:iterator value="OnlineActionList" var="calst">
                </s:iterator>
            </s:if>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:if>
</s:form>
```

Action Class

```
public class SupplierPaidAction extends ActionSupport {
private long paidId;
private long supplierPaymentId;
private float amount;
private float paidAmount;
private String payment_mode;
private Date paymentDate;
private Timestamp addDate;
private String dataStatus;
private long ccold;
private ArrayList<SupplierPaidAction> paidList;
private ArrayList<CashAction> cashActionList;
private ArrayList<DDAction> DDActionList;
private ArrayList<OnlinePaymentAction> OnlineActionList;
//getter and setter of all fields

 public String update() {
        System.out.println("-> SupplierPaidAction update()");
        System.out.println(getPaidId() + " " + getAmount()
        + " " + getPaymentDate()+" "+getPaidList().get(0).getCashActionList()
            +" "+getDDActionList()+" "+getOnlineActionList());
return SUCCESS;
}


public Timestamp getAddDate() {
        return addDate;
    }

    public void setAddDate(Timestamp addDate) {
        this.addDate = addDate;
    }

    public String getDataStatus() {
        return dataStatus;
    }

    public void setDataStatus(String dataStatus) {
        this.dataStatus = dataStatus;
    }

    public long getSupplierPaymentId() {
        return supplierPaymentId;
    }

    public void setSupplierPaymentId(long supplierPaymentId) {
        this.supplierPaymentId = supplierPaymentId;
    }

    public int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public void setCurrentPage(int currentPage) {
        this.currentPage = currentPage;
    }

    public LoginCheck getLc() {
        return lc;
    }

    public void setLc(LoginCheck lc) {
        this.lc = lc;
    }

    public int getP() {
        return p;
    }

    public void setP(int p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public long getTotalCount() {
        return totalCount;
    }

    public void setTotalCount(long totalCount) {
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
    }

    public int getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public void setTotalPages(int totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public ArrayList<SupplierPaidAction> getPaidList() {
        return paidList;
    }

    public void setPaidList(ArrayList<SupplierPaidAction> paidList) {
        this.paidList = paidList;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public long getPaidId() {
        return paidId;
    }

    public void setPaidId(long PaidId) {
        this.paidId = PaidId;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Date getPaymentDate() {
        return paymentDate;
    }

    public void setPaymentDate(Date paymentDate) {
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
    }

    public String getPayment_mode() {
        return payment_mode;
    }

    public void setPayment_mode(String payment_mode) {
        this.payment_mode = payment_mode;
    }

    public float getPaidAmount() {
        return paidAmount;
    }

    public void setPaidAmount(float paidAmount) {
        this.paidAmount = paidAmount;
    }

    public CashBean getCashBean() {
        return cashBean;
    }

    public void setCashBean(CashBean cashBean) {
        this.cashBean = cashBean;
    }
  public ArrayList<CashAction> getCashActionList() {
        return cashActionList;
    }

    public void setCashActionList(ArrayList<CashAction> cashActionList) {
        this.cashActionList = cashActionList;
    }

    public ArrayList<DDAction> getDDActionList() {
        return DDActionList;
    }

    public void setDDActionList(ArrayList<DDAction> DDActionList) {
        this.DDActionList = DDActionList;
    }

    public ArrayList<OnlinePaymentAction> getOnlineActionList() {
        return OnlineActionList;
    }

    public void setOnlineActionList(ArrayList<OnlinePaymentAction> OnlineActionList) {
        this.OnlineActionList = OnlineActionList;
    }

    public long getCcold() {
        return ccold;
    }

    public void setCcold(long ccold) {
        this.ccold = ccold;
    }
}
```

How to fetch value of ArrayList(`cashActionList`,`DDActionList`,`OnlineActionList`) from jsp to action

Comment: Could you post the action class?

Comment: My action class is `SupplierPaidAction`

Comment: I have Many other method on it

Comment: dont you have getters and setters in your action for the arraylist?

Comment: @A5l-lE5 updated with getter and setter

Comment: which value of paidlist you wanted to fetch you are showing it using itrator ,you can only get the values till its binded to select or checkbox or any other inputing field as you wanted to update so must be chosen or an input by the user

Comment: @xrcwrn you should also post nested classes, so ppl could now how and where to map your form fields.

Comment: @A5l-lE5 I am fetcing values to input box now user can update its value according to its need then user will resubmit the form

Comment: your selected value by the user is now binded to textfiled then how would you get from this ->  getPaidList().get(0).getCashActionList()

Comment: I am not getting it. I am trying it randomly

Comment: @A5l-lE5 So how can I assign values to arraylist

Comment: you wanted the user to select and option from your arraylist  and then you wanted to update it an an option?

Comment: @A5l-lE5 Yes, I want to Assing all jsp pages value to `paidList`. How to do this

Comment: if you want one of the values from arraylist then use select or radio button and then on submit of that form you will have the values in your action

Comment: Not One or two value. I want to assing value to object